# how can I split a string in python with variable characters?

Tags: string, split

There is a way in python to use the "split" function whit some parametric symbol

for example i need to split a string like this: "example[1]of[2]a[3]string" in every "[*]" where * could be any character

need this:
"example[1]of[2]a[3]string".split("[*]") --> ["example","of","a","string"]